# Spinner SetAdapter Problems and Questions

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

I am trying to make a spinner and I find so many tutorials on Internet.
But it always causes error. ( Null object reference )

> Q1 : why i write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); before`
>   Spinner dynamicSpinner = (Spinner)
>   findViewById(R.id.spinnerFindType);` it still causes Null Error ?
>
> Q2 : My spinner is in another xml ( find_fragment ) , so should i change
>   from `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to
>   `setContentView(R.layout.find_fragment);` ?
>   but this is in the MainActivity.java

Thnak you so much !

Here is my code.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ---------------------------- Init Menu slider -----------------------------------
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); // show Icon
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    displayView(R.id.menu_about); // First page to About
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Spinner dynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFindType);

    String[] items = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items); // Use String[] , Dynamic

    dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    dynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

My logcat :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                               at com.example.user.foody.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:120)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)

Comment: You either need to add the spinner in the activity_main.xml or create the fragment in this activity and then link the spinner to it.

Comment: And y is your spinner in find_fragment ?

Comment: @Basanth Hi , thank you for your reply.
I make a slide menu, and all of  pages are fragment.
And i make a spinner in a one of fragments ( in find_fragment.xml ).

Comment: @Basanth Sorry, I am new to android studio. I don't know what's that mean " create the fragment in this activity" ?

Comment: Share your xml of activity

Comment: @Kevin you need to understand how fragments work before getting into this. This tutorial should get you started with making use of fragments along with the Slide menu. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: @Godwin Ok post it

Comment: Thank you guys !! I finally debug it !! that's so great !!

Comment: @Kevin I've added the comment as the answer so that other can benefit with it. You can go ahead and accept it if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how fragments work before getting into this. This tutorial should get you started with making use of fragments along with the Slide menu. [Fragment Navigation Drawer](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)